# GitHub Actions Reuse Steps

Tags: github, yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

I have GitHub Actions file where I have jobs in the order of `Release` and `Build` and `Publish`.

I have `slack_success` and `slack_fail` also.

The trouble is, I want to send to Slack a `slack_fail` at any point any of the Jobs being run fails.

I had hoped `- uses: slack_fail` would have worked but it fails to even run the file as it claims its not correct.

I would also like to be notified on `slack_success` also at each successful Job too. I just don't want to post the same code over and over into each Job, would like to have a DRY approach.

```
name: My Task

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  slack_success:
    name: Pass - Notify on Slack
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: always() && steps.semantic-release.outcome == 'success'
    steps:
      - uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.23.0
        with:
          channel-id: "GBBCJN3GC"
          slack-message: "GitHub build result: ${{ job.status }}\n${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url || github.event.head_commit.url }}"
        env:
          SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN }}

  slack_fail:
    name: Failed - Notify on Slack
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: failure() && steps.semantic-release.outcome != 'success'
    steps:
      - uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.23.0
        with:
          channel-id: "GBBCJN3GC"
          slack-message: "GitHub build result: ${{ job.status }}\n${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url || github.event.head_commit.url }}"
        env:
          SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN }}

  release:
    name: Release
    permissions:
      contents: write
      issues: write
      pull-requests: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 18
          registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
      - run: npm ci
      - name: Semantic Release
        id: semantic-release
        run: npx semantic-release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
      - uses: slack_success
      - uses: slack_fail

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: always()
    needs: [release]
    steps:
      - run: npm run build
      - uses: slack_success
      - uses: slack_fail

  publish:
    name: Publish Package
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: always()
    needs: build
    steps:
      - run: cd dist/my-lib && npm publish
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
      - uses: slack_success
      - uses: slack_fail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions to achieve this, one is by using a [composite action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action) for `slack_success` and `slack_fail` and then you call it after your workflow finishes.

The other one is to have a job that depends (with [`needs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds)) on all other jobs which will report the status of each pipeline.

For the first approach, you may create this file tree:

```
.github
├── actions
│   ├── slack-failure
│   │   └── action.yaml
│   └── slack-success
│       └── action.yaml
└── workflows
    └── my-task.yaml
```

In `actions/slack-success/action.yaml` for example:

```
name: Send Slack success message
description: Sends a slack message on workflow success

inputs:
  job-status:
    required: true
    description: Github job status

runs:
  using: composite
  steps:
    - uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.23.0
      with:
        channel-id: "GBBCJN3GC"
        slack-message: "GitHub build result: ${{ inputs.job-status }}\n${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url || github.event.head_commit.url }}"
```

And in your workflow you would have something like:

```
name: My Task

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  release:
    name: Release
    permissions:
      contents: write
      issues: write
      pull-requests: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 18
          registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
      - run: npm ci
      - name: Semantic Release
        id: semantic-release
        run: npx semantic-release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
      - name: Report Slack success
        if: success() && steps.semantic-release.outcome == 'success'
        uses: ./.github/actions/slack-success
        with:
            job-status: ${{ job.status }}
      - name: Report slack failure
        if: failure() || cancelled() || steps.semantic-release.outcome != 'success'
        uses: ./.github/actions/slack-failure
        with:
            job-status: ${{ job.status }}
```

You can definitely tweak this and make it less verbose, for example you may not need that `job.status` as you know that it's either `success` or `failure` or `cancelled` (see more at [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#status-check-functions)).

---

The second approach is to use a dependant job to report your "success" jobs:

```
jobs:
  slack_success:
    needs:
      - release
      - build
      - publish
    name: Pass - Notify on Slack
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.23.0
        with:
          channel-id: "GBBCJN3GC"
          slack-message: "GitHub build result: ${{ job.status }}\n${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url || github.event.head_commit.url }}"
        env:
          SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN }}
```

This means that you will send the slack message only if all 3 jobs are done altogether.

And for the "failure" report:

```
  slack_fail:
    needs:
      - release
      - build
      - publish
    name: Failed - Notify on Slack
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: failure() || cancelled()
    steps:
      - uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.23.0
        with:
          channel-id: "GBBCJN3GC"
          slack-message: "GitHub build result: ${{ job.status }}\n${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url || github.event.head_commit.url }}"
        env:
          SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Appreciate this! I've tried the first approach which I have working.

Will try the latter approach but would like to see each job branch off to show it either Success or Fail on each step.